# Prove the series does not converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Prove the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

So what I am thinking is that the pointwise summation is $e^x$ and that I need to show there is no $n\geq N$ so that $|\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n-e^xn!}{n!}| \leq \epsilon$, for all x . We haven't covered integration; if someone could give me a hint on how to show the series does not converge uniformly, that we be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The terms of the sum do not converge uniformly to $0$ on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the function and the partial sum
$$e^x-\sum\limits_{n=0}^k\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
is bounded? Answer: no. Why?

Comment: Because if we fixed $k$ and let $x -> \infty$ then $e^x$ grows much faster than the partial sum? Then the difference would continue to grow as x approaches infinity.

Comment: True. And the difference between the function and the partial sum cannot be small. BTW, edit required in your post, because $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n-e^xn!}{n!}=-\infty$.

Comment: @Fluke_of_Luke ehm why e^x grows much faster than the partial sum? It seems to me that it should be justified..