# Prove $\sum_0^\infty x^k/k!$ does not converge uniformly to $e^x$ on the entire real line R.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, uniform-convergence

> Prove $\sum_0^\infty x^k/k!$ does not converge uniformly to $e^x$ on
>   the entire real line R.

I know that this power series converges absolutely and uniformly over any compact interval, [$a,b$], however, I am unsure how to prove that this does not hold beyond this interval.

Comment: First prove that if a series converges uniformly to a function on a set, then the individual terms converge uniformly to the zero function on the set. Then use a sup argument to show that we don't have uniform convergence to 0 on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Consider the following link. It may help you.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648769/prove-the-series-does-not-converge-uniformly

Comment: I understand what is stated in that other post, I'm just unsure how to prove it is uniformly convergent now. How can I prove that it is uniformly convergent over a fixed domain now? If I fix my domain as [0,1], how can I prove that the error can be made as small as possible?

Comment: @user282934 M-test works in a compact set

Comment: @Nitin  initially did use the M-test which was how I determined that it would be uniformly convergent over a compact set. I am now wondering if I would be able to directly prove that is does uniformly converge on a compact interval by using the method described here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652696/prove-xn-is-not-uniformly-convergent - If I'm not mistaken, you were referring to this in your first comment.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: if $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $\mathbb R$, then $f - f_n$ must be bounded for some $n$.

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor series with Lagrange remainder
$$
e^x=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}+\frac{(e^x)^{(2n)}|_t}{2n!}x^{2n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}+\frac{e^t}{2n!}x^{2n}
$$
where $|t|<|x|$. If it converges uniformly to $e^x$on the entire real line, then given $\epsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that for any $n>N$ and $x\in\Bbb{R}$, there is
$$
\left|e^x-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right|=\left|\frac{e^t}{2n!}x^{2n}\right|<\epsilon
$$
But this is not true for if fix $n$, we can always find $x$ large enough ($e^{-t}\geqslant1$) so that 
$$
\left|x^{2n}\right|>\frac{2n!}{e^t}\epsilon\quad\text{and }\quad\left|\frac{e^t}{2n!}x^{2n}\right|>\epsilon
$$
So this series doesn't converge uniformly to $e^x$on the entire real line $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an alternative proof can come from using L'Hospital's rule, that for any finite Taylor series polynomial, we know that $lim_{x-->\infty} \frac{e^x}{T_n (x)} = \infty$, which violates uniform convergence.